# Multiple Macs Controlled by single USB IR Receiver

Tags: usb, mac, ir-receiver

I am looking to connect a single IR receiver to multiple mac mini computers to advance a slideshow played through front row in sync. I was reading this post below from superuser.com and one of the replies suggested that I post the question here. Currently we use a single IR receiver for each Mac computer and advance the slideshow with an apple remote. Our current method works but IR interference sometimes causes a Mac to not advance. I was thinking that if I could connect a single IR Receiver to multiple macs I could advance the slideshow in each mini from a single receiver without any misfires.

User: Chris Stratton suggests building a "number of usb-slave-enabled micro-controllers (one per PC) to a usb-host-enabled one (for the keyboard) using their serial ports."

I am new to electronics and would like to know if this is a viable solution and if so could you give me some direction as to how I could build this.

IR Receiver: http://twistedmelon.com/mira/hardware.html
Similar Post from: https://superuser.com/questions/367276/would-a-usb-hub-work-in-reverse

Comment: Are all of these displays showing the same thing?  If so, might be easier to split the output as opposed to trying to have a multi-remote.

Comment: No. Each display has a different image. Essentially what we have done is created the same slideshow effect as connecting multiple slide projectors and advancing slides in synch.

Comment: What about just using IR repeaters? Alternatively, if the machines are networked you could use one machine to send an advance command to the others - AppleScript should let you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this could be a viable solution. This is commercially known as a IR Repeater system. It would not require any usb, as a microcontroller can read the IR signal, and repeat it to multiple IR transmitters/leds. A google search for "microcontroller IR Repeater" will provide a multitude of projects that you can build off of.

Alternatively, as @MathewHall suggested, if you are on the same network, one of the macs could act as a server to control the other ones. [There are applications that can use the same IR remote to launch or control a custom application or script. (from the Apple Stack Exchange)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52969/using-apples-ir-remote-to-simulate-a-left-right-mouse-click-or-navigate-present). With some basic coding, you can have it done in software, no hardware to make or replace if broken. And easier to expand if needed.